# How do I fix Import HTML URL ERROR "cant fetch URL"?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

Im trying to import a table from a website by using=importhtml, and it was working fine for a week. But now its saying cant fetch URL even after I retype it or try to upload any new website table data. How do I fix this issue?